# Sending an iPhone app to customer for review

Tags: iphone

For a review at the customers side we would like to email him a prerelease of the app (it is in a prerelease state, so not available at the iTunes store). What is the best way so he can install the app on his iPhone?

thx in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do ad Hoc distribution (which requieres the more expensive "enterprise" developer license) or you can ask your customer for his phone's UDID, add it to the devices section on the iphone developer portal, afterwards add the device to the profisioningprofile of your app.

ad Hoc distribution is not necessary in this case. I have 50 Beta testers on my current app and have them all provisioned manually (which is a pain for 50 devices, but still...)

I think you can save the additional cost of aquiring an ad Hoc developer license.

Comment: thx for your answer. so I add the id and can send the app by email to my customer? does he need something else than the app itself?

Comment: yes, he needs a copy of the provisioning file as well. make sure you add the device first, add it to your profile, download the profile, add it to xcode (simply by opening it) build your project afterwards and then send the executable and the provisioning file to your customer. he then has to connect his iphone to itunes, import the provisioning file first and afterwards the executable. the instal procedure can be found here (i usually send this link togehter with my releasenotes) http://forum.voxilla.com/rf-support-forum/install-ad-hoc-distribution-iphone-ipod-touch-application-33448.html

Comment: Ad Hoc distribution does NOT require the enterprise developer account.

Comment: also checkout testflightapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Ad Hoc distribution. See iPhone Developer Portal on how to do this.